# Memory size reported by /proc/meminfo is less than my physical RAM

Tags: ram

My laptop is having a total of 4GB RAM, but when I type `/proc/meminfo` it is showing only 2.5GB in Ubuntu 14.04. Why it is showing less memory than the actual?

Answer (score 3):

It's a common practice on laptops. The Graphic memory is usually shared with the main RAM of the system and it is dynamic, which means it increases and decreases on demand.

It can grow until 1,7 GB, and this value seems standard if you have a system with 4,0 GB of RAM, on Intel systems it's called **DVMT**:

> Dynamic Video Memory Technology (**DVMT**) is a method for dynamically
>   allocating system memory for use as graphics memory to balance 2D/3D
>   graphics and system performance. If your computer is configured to use
>   DVMT, graphics memory is allocated based on system requirements and
>   application demands (up to the configured maximum amount). When memory
>   is no longer needed by an application, the dynamically allocated
>   portion of memory is returned to the operating system for other uses.
>
> Many graphic-intensive applications (especially games) require a
>   minimum amount of video memory in order to run correctly (or to run at
>   all). Video memory is allocated based on the amount requested by the
>   operating system. When the memory is no longer required, it is
>   returned to the operating system for use by other applications or
>   system functions.
>
> DVMT allocates memory based on system needs. Some newer systems have
>   an option in the system BIOS that adjusts the amount of memory
>   available for DVMT. Memory can be allocated up to the maximum limit
>   set by the graphics driver. Unlike previous operating systems, Windows
>   Vista* and Windows 7* have greater control over memory management and
>   determines the amount of the graphics memory together with the Intel®
>   Graphics Driver.

Source: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029090.htm